# Intel SGX Enclave store data between ECALLs

Tags: c++, intel-sgx

How can I keep data preserved between ECALLs? (not nested ECALLs) I found two ways: a global array 2)seal data, transfer them outside the enclave and transfer them back inside with the next ECALL, unseal and to recover the current state. Are there more ways? I saw that some implementations use a global pointer and initialise a new object inside a function and reference it, but how can this work and the object is not destroyed after the trusted function returns, like in a regular C++ environment?